# How can the following TeX file be run without errors?

Tags: xetex, errors, packages, xepersian

I get an error :

```
! I can't find file `xdvipdfmx.cfg'.

l.6 \input xdvipdfmx.cfg

Please type another input file name
```

and

```
! Emergency stop.

l.6 \input xdvipdfmx.cfg
```

I really wish to know what this LaTeX message means! and how I can solve or ignore it?
TexStudio shows the line number of the error where I use the `\package{fmultico}`, but I know it does not cause the problem because by erasing the line the problem remains in that empty line!

I even downlod a lot files and place them where the file exists but only this error was changed into 100! another errors that are not correct, because by clearing their lines they remains at their place.

I think without the LaTeX code nobody can solve the problem so I put it here,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{fmultico}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pstricks}
%\usepackage{tocbibind}
% بسته‌ای برای ظاهر شدن «مراجع» و «نمایه» در فهرست مطالب
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
%\usepackage[notbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{persianpoem}
%\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xy}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=4cm,bottom=2.8cm,right=2.5cm,head=1cm,foot=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Zar}
\newtheorem{preproof}{{\bf اثبات }\hspace{-.15cm}}
\renewcommand{\thepreproof}{}
\newenvironment{prf}[1]{\begin{preproof}{\rm
           #1}\hfill{$\blacksquare$}}{\end{preproof}}

\newtheorem{preexample}{{\bf مثال }\hspace{-.15cm}}
\renewcommand{\thepreexample}{}
\newenvironment{example}[1]{\begin{preexample}{\rm
           #1}\hfill{$\clubsuit$}}{\end{preexample}}


\theoremstyle{plain}% default
\newtheorem{thm}{قضیه}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{لم}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{گزاره}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{حدس}
\newtheorem{corollary}[thm]{نتیجه}
\newtheorem{question}[thm]{پرسش}
\newtheorem{defin}[thm]{تعریف}
\begin{document}
\title{اینجا نام مقاله مورد نظر خود را بنویسید}
\author{اسم و مشخصات خود رااینجا بنویسید}
\maketitle
\abstract
اینجا چکیده متن خود را بنویسید. اینجا چکیده متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا چکیده متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا چکیده متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا چکیده متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا چکیده متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا چکیده متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا چکیده متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا چکیده متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا چکیده متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا چکیده متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا چکیده متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا چکیده متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا چکیده متن خود را بنویسید.

\section{اینجا نام بخش اول را بنویسید}
اینجا  شروع به نوشتن متن خود کنید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید. اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
 اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
 اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
 اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
 اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
 اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.

 \begin{defin}
 اینجا  تعریف  را بنویسید.

\end{defin}
\begin{thm}
اینجا  قضیه خود را بنویسید.

\end{thm}
\begin{lem}
اینجا  لم  را بنویسید.

 \end{lem}
 \begin{prop}
 اینجا  گزاره  را بنویسید.

 \end{prop}
 \begin{question}
اینجا  سوال خود را بنویسید.

\end{question}
\begin{conj}
اینجا  حدس خود را بنویسید.

\end{conj}
\begin{prf}{
اینجا اثبات  را بنویسید.

}
\end{prf}

\begin{lem}\label{pr1}
در این لم نحوه برچسب گذاری نمایش داده شده است.

\end{lem}

با توجه به لم \ref{pr1} داریم

در اینجا به مقاله \cite{MR1722215}  ارجاع داده شده است.
اینجا نام بخش اول را بنویسید

\chapter{اینجا نام فصل دوم را بنویسید}
\section{اینجا نام بخش دوم را بنویسید}
اینجا  شروع به نوشتن متن خود کنید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید. اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.
اینجا  متن خود را بنویسید.

\begin{defin}
اینجا  تعریف  را بنویسید.

\end{defin}
\begin{thm}
اینجا  قضیه خود را بنویسید.

\end{thm}
\begin{lem}
اینجا  لم  را بنویسید.

\end{lem}
\begin{prop}
اینجا  گزاره  را بنویسید.

\end{prop}
\begin{question}
اینجا  سوال خود را بنویسید.

\end{question}
\begin{conj}
اینجا  حدس خود را بنویسید.

\end{conj}
\begin{prf}{
اینجا اثبات  را بنویسید.

}
\end{prf}

\begin{thm}\label{abc}
در این قضیه نحوه برچسب گذاری نمایش داده شده است.

\end{thm}

با توجه به قضیه \ref{abc} و لم \ref{pr1} داریم

در اینجا به مقاله \cite{MR1722215}  ارجاع داده شده است.

در اینجا به مقاله \cite{MR1475894}  ارجاع داده شده است.


\begin{latin}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\renewcommand\refname{{\rightline{\rl{مراجع}}}}

\bibliography{MyReferences}
\end{latin} 

\end{document}
```

The new errors are here:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.70 \ExplSyntaxOn
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.71 \bool
_set_false:N \g_fontspec_math_bool
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.71 \bool_
set_false:N \g_fontspec_math_bool
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.71 \bool_
set_false:N \g_fontspec_math_bool
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 71.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd"
File: umsa.fd 2009/06/22 v3.00 AMS symbols A
)

...

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
9619 strings out of 430430
144279 string characters out of 3189573
343545 words of memory out of 3000000
12645 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
12829 words of font info for 42 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
44i,32n,53p,586b,323s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
No pages of output.
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Without an example of code it's impossible to help you.

Comment: I mean that if we're not put in the condition of reproducing the error, it's impossible to give advice.

Comment: The file is part of the base of PStricks. I suspect there is something not quite right with your TeX installation: what operating system and TeX set up do you use?

Comment: @JosephWright , please describe more for me what I should answer to your question that "What operatig system and TeX set up do you use?"

Comment: @AmirHoseinSadeghiManesh I tried your example and it compiles without errors. I suspect you're using an outdated (or corrupt) TeX distribution.

Comment: @AmirHoseinSadeghiManesh Can you show the first 20 lines in the log file?

Comment: The line number (l.6.) doesn't refer to your main document but to the document latex is currently reading. The log-file should show you which one this is (most probably pstricks.con from the pstricks package). The log-file also contains the requested informations about your tex system.

Comment: @egreg , the site didn't let me to bring all errors here but I think it is enough and they are error not warning.

Comment: @AmirHoseinSadeghiManesh I asked for the first 20 lines. However, the excerpt tells that you are indeed using an outdated TeX distribution. Install MiKTeX version 2.9

Comment: Ok, I will do and then will report the result.

Comment: @AmirHoseinSadeghiManesh: See [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your complete MWE with XeLaTeX using an updated MikTeX 2.9 (64-bit version under Win 7-64 in case it matters) and had no problems getting it to work. I had to comment out the `\settextfont{XB Zar}` because I did not have it in my system. I found a [discussion on a similar problem](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2010-03/msg00619.html) with earlier MiKTeX versions which may indcate that an update of your LaTeX packages may solve the problem.

Comment: I had downloaded "xdvipdfmx.cfg" even!

Comment: Yes, my previous LiveTex that I got it from one IT student has problem. I removed it and downloaded it from its main source again. Now I have no problem.